# 3 steps form bootstrapValidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using bootstrapValidator on a 3 steps registration form. I'm going to validate it step by step and if one step is valid, user can go to next step. How can I validate each step separately from other steps and finally send all three steps data to server?
currently I can validate it, but it's not step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/ or on http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ check our Toggling example

Comment: yah, when I validate one step the other steps fields should be disabled. so the BootstrapValidator won't validate them.

Answer (score 0):

You could give "exclude" option a try.

[Settings form-excluded](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#form-excluded)